# put a button in frameLayaout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

I have a small application with the camera and I have a device which is not a problem but if I can change the app will improve much aesthetically.

I put the xml code of the activity:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/layout">



    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip">

    </FrameLayout>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/obutrador2" >

    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I run the application, there is a white stripe along the entire height of the screen occupied by the button. How I can fix this? It would make the button appear above the image that the camera is capturing, as the app that has the default phone.

The problem is how to position the frame layout so that it fills the screen and center the button at the bottom. If I make the FrameLayout full-screen, the button disappears.

I leave a link to a photo of what happens:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jbns8jddtwxjhdp/IMAG0348.jpg

Comment: Please upload a picture of what this layout looks like then add a link to the pic to your question.

Comment: sorry, I forgot, seeing is better understood

Comment: Can you do a screen capture instead of taking a photograph?

Comment: At a glance, I see that you set the height of the FrameLayout to "0dpi". Most likely you want it larger than that.

Comment: Sorry, but now I can not upload the screenshot, tomorrow morning the i will upload the screenshoot

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I just fix the problem, I removed the linear layout and place I put the FrameLayout is now at least FrameLayout fill the screen, but the button is gone but if it works to tighten.

Comment: Have you tried placing the button inside the FrameLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should define Button inside the FrameLayout like this.
You can make FrameLayout as parent layout and you can place button where ever you want

```
<FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/obutrador2" >

    </Button>

</FrameLayout>
```

Hope This should be work for you...Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried to do what I say, but either puts me in the middle or puts me at the top left ... Can you think of to put it down at all and focused?

Comment: i set gravity bottom and center, but the button is gone, but if I touch on the screen at the bottom center of the picture is